# How to handle multiple data attributes with jQuery filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, custom-data-type

Using [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/6/), what if you wanted to handle more than one data attribute.  For example, if the first one could be blue OR red, it would have an attribute of `data-colour="Blue, Red"`.  How can I update the jQuery to handle this?  In other words, it would now need to search for the `data-value` within the entire `data-colour` string, not just an exact match.

Is this doable within the code below?

HTML:

```
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue"  data-size="medium">
  Blue medium</div>
  <div  data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue"  data-size="medium">
  Blue medium</div>
  <div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue" data-size="large">
  Blue large </div>
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Red" data-size="small">
  Red Small</div>
  <div data-brand="Addidas" data-price="31" data-colour="Red" data-size="small">
  Red Small</div>
Colours: Blue <input type="checkbox" id="BlueCB" data-type="colour" data-value="Blue" checked> 
Red <input class="chbx" type="checkbox" id="RedCB" data-type="colour" data-value="Red" checked>
Brand: Nike <input type="checkbox" id="NikeCB" data-type='brand'  data-value='Nike' checked>
Size: Large<input type="checkbox" id="LargeCB" data-type="Size"  data-value='large' checked>
Size: Medium<input type="checkbox" id="MediumCB" data-type="Size"  data-value='medium' checked>
```

JS:

```
var $boxes = $('input[data-type]'), //all input boxes with data-type attribute
    $dataObjects =$(); //will be filled with all bound data elements
$boxes.each(function(ind, inp){     //create filter information
    var type = inp.dataset.type, value = inp.dataset.value; //for older browsers, use  $(inp).data('type')  
  var filter =  'div[data-' + type +'="' + value +'"]';     
  inp.dataset.filter = filter;
    $.merge($dataObjects,$(filter));
}); 

$boxes.change(function(){
    var blacklist = $boxes.filter(function(i,b){return !b.checked})
    .map(function(i,b){return b.dataset.filter}).toArray().join();
  $dataObjects.hide().not(blacklist).show();
});
```

Comment: You can check if any string `includes` any other string. `var str = 'I like red and I like blue'; str.includes('red') // true`  `str.includes('blue'); // true`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Is your colour name fix in **data-colour** attribute ? like Red, Blue or does it contains any colour ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the page of [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

An OR is easy enough, you can just include multiple attributes one after the other:

```
...filter("[data-colour*='red'][data-colour*='blue']")...
```

The text comparison is case sensitive.

In regard to [filtering](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), you can `filter()` the DOM elements from your existing list, filter the `children()` thereof, filter the descendants with `find()`, filter the `parent()` or `parents()`, or even search everything with `contents()` (although I don't think attributes would work against `contents()`).